# Why does gulp error when passing the `done` function to Karma's server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, karma-runner

Just writing a (so far) very simple gulpfile and I am perplexed by an error I have come across.

When the tests fail with this task, gulp exits gracefully

```
gulp.task('test', done => {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, () => done()).start();
});
```

...produces:

```
Chrome 50.0.2661 (Mac OS X 10.11.3): Executed 11 of 11 (3 FAILED) (0.053 secs / 0.023 secs)
[17:38:02] Finished 'test' after 2.43 s
```

But when you slim it down to just pass `done` into Karma, it fails rather ungracefully

```
gulp.task('test', done => {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});
```

...produces:

```
Chrome 50.0.2661 (Mac OS X 10.11.3): Executed 11 of 11 (3 FAILED) (0.066 secs / 0.042 secs)
[17:36:39] 'test' errored after 2.45 s
[17:36:39] Error: 1
    at formatError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/markstickley/workspace/timewarp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /Users/markstickley/workspace/timewarp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/Users/markstickley/workspace/timewarp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/Users/markstickley/workspace/timewarp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at removeAllListeners (/Users/markstickley/workspace/timewarp/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:336:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/markstickley/workspace/timewarp/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:347:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1518:8)
    at doNTCallback1 (node.js:418:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:340:17)
```

Can anyone explain why this happens, given that `done` is a function and all the wrapped version of `done` does is call `done`?

Answer (score 4):

Further research has revealed that Karma resolves the callback passed to it with an exit code (https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/dev/public-api.html):

```
var Server = require('karma').Server
var server = new Server({port: 9876}, function(exitCode) {
  console.log('Karma has exited with ' + exitCode)
  process.exit(exitCode)
})
```

And that gulp will quit the run if `done` is passed any argument other than `null` or `undefined` (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps-fn):

```
gulp.task('one', function(cb) {
    // do stuff -- async or otherwise
    cb(err); // if err is not null and not undefined, the run will stop, and note that it failed
});
```

So Karma's exit code is causing gulp to exit prematurely when `done` is passed directly to Karma as a callback. Wrapping it in a function means that `done` is still called but without any arguments -- causing normal completion.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wouldn't have understood it properly without you :)

Answer (score 1):

Mark,

A couple of things.

I had exactly the same issue understanding what gulp was doing with the callback and how it all worked. First and foremost we must understand that gulp allows you to have two syntaxes. One where you return from the task function and gulp can get on with its subsequent tasks, and the other where you must provide a callback for the same purpose. These are equivalent:

```
gulp.task('Returns', function(){
    return gulp.src(...).pipe(...)
})

gulp.task('Returns', function(done){
    gulp.src(...).pipe(...)
})
```

On the other hand javascript being the powerful language that it is allows us to write some horrific and terror inducing code. For that reason I like to break things down a little.

Translating the first function into human readable code:

**Step 1**

```
function get_karma_server(){
    return new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }
}

gulp.task('test', done => {
    get_karma_server }, () => done()).start();
});
```

*done* is defined as the content of whatever is inside *{ }* curly braces. *Comma*. But a gulp task requires a function to execute. Ok, the function to execute is the execution of get_karma_server which returns the instance of the server and *.start()*

If that doesn't make you vomit I don't know what does.

**This is why it doesn't work**

If you don't execute the function then you don't have an instance of the server ,which means that start is not a function of undefined which means that gulp doesn't get its callback. Hence all the callback related errors.

**Step 2**

```
function get_karma_server(){
    return new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }
}

gulp.task('test', function(done){
    get_karma_server().start();
});
```

Still equivalent, but now it makes a little more sense. *done* is still the callback to gulp.

**Step 3**

```
function get_karma_server(){
    return new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }
}

gulp.task('test', function(){
    return get_karma_server().start();
});
```

The same function but this time we just return instead of providing a callback if you are not using it.

**Suggestion**

```
gulp.task('test', function(the_gulp_callback_aka_done){

    // Initialize and get the instance of the server
    var karma = require('karma').Server;

    // setup your configuration. This could live somewhere else
    var config = {
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    };

    // the karma callback
    function karma_Callback(){
        // Do something here after karma is done running your tests
    }

    karma.start(config, karma_Callback);
});
```

Be verbose. It is not any slower at run-time and it is a heck of a lot faster to understand.

**-------------- Edit --------------**

@Mark, my apologizes. I understood the question but did not convey the message. It is not a matter of ES5 vs ES6.

The parenthesis () syntax is used for execution, right?. You can execute something that is not a function but javascript will try to execute it nonetheless giving errors and what not.

In this case you could just provide karma with a function by name, say x, then karma will take x and call () on it by means of x(). Right? This is because it is expecting x to be a function to call after it is done processing your tests. Hence the call-back.

Now, within x javascript will execute everything just like a regular function but then it runs into this *done* thing and it does not know what to do with it because x itself does not take a call back.

**In code:**

```
function x(){
    // get things done here
}

function x(callback_for_x){
    // get things done here

    // ok, I'm done. call the callback_for_x
    callback_for_x();
}
```

Using done within this version of x:

```
function x(){
    // get things done here
    // and...
    done; // Get ready for some errors
}
```

Using done here will work just fine.

```
function x(callback_for_x){
    // get things done here

    // ok, I'm done. call the callback_for_x
    callback_for_x();
}
```

However, we have the first version of x as a callback to karma, which means that we must manually call done:

```
function x(){
    // get things done here
    // and...
    done(); // Now gulp can continue because it's callback was called.
}
```

I hope that made more sense. I hate it when I'm incoherent and this post has gone longer than it was supposed to.

Comment: Hi Wilmer, thank you so much for your detailed answer. I'm afraid however that I think either I have misunderstood your answer or you have misunderstood the question. In particular I think there may be some misinterpretation of the use of es6 arrow functions in regards to `done`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions  When I get back to my computer I can post an es5 version without arrow functions that exhibits exactly the same behaviour which is really peculiar - I can only imagine it is some sort of scope issue that I have yet to fathom...

Comment: In es5:

    gulp.task('test', function(done) {
        new KarmaServer({
            configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }, function() { done(); }).start();
    });

vs.

    gulp.task('test', function(done) {
        new KarmaServer({
            configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }, done).start();
    });

Comment: @MarkStickley I added the answer as an edit because it was too long.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Ok so I think I understand now. However, I was under the impression that `done` (being a function that you have to call when your task is complete) was callable in the same way as a function(){} which in turn calls `done` is also callable. Another assumption I am working under is that I am passing this function to karma to be called when the tests are complete. Are any of my assumptions incorrect? I think that you are saying I am trying to execute something that is not executable but when I call typeof on `done` I get "function"...

Comment: @MarkStickley I think both of your assumptions are incorrect. 1. `done` is a function that is called implicitly by the task once it is done. You don't have to call it explicitly although you may (this is particularly confusing). 2. You can pass `done` as a parameter to a function that expects such a parameter to be a function definition where you can assume and test that `done` is called. 3. You can pass `done` as a parameter anywhere you want, but if the function that you are passing `done` to does not expect a function definition you must execute it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for making me questions my assumptions and knowledge about gulp and Karma - a little investigation showed that there were forces in play that I wasn't aware of... hence my answer :)